# Playing audio and recording together iOS 7 and later

Tags: ios, ios7, audio-recording, avaudiosession

I want to **record and play sound as same time**. As I can play once I complete the recording. But I want to both action at same time. As many articles describe that **AudioSessionSetProperty** is helpful to keep both things running together. But it's not working in iOS7.

Can anybody suggest any idea or articles which help to do this ?

Thanks in advance.